# Control individual axis lines of facets in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I would like to make a plot with multiple facets by column where the axis lines alternate between each column. For example, the following code will generate a plot where the x axis line and ticks are both on the bottom.

```
  dat <- data.frame(type = rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 10), x = 1:10, y = rnorm(20))

  ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap( ~ type, scales = 'free_y') +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line())
```

But I want the x axis line and ticks to be on the bottom for the left panel and on the top for the right panel. An example of what I am looking for is below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZvJU.jpg)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowlegde that could not be achieved out-of-the-box. However, one approach to achieve your desired result and in general to get more freedom in styling different facets would be to make separate plots and glue them together using e.g. `pacthwork`. Note however that this approach also has its drawbacks, like. e.g. duplicated axis labels.

```r
dat <- data.frame(type = rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 10), x = 1:10, y = rnorm(20))

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(patchwork)

make_plot <- function(.type, axis.pos) {
  dat <- filter(dat, type %in% .type)
  ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    scale_x_continuous(position = axis.pos) +
    facet_wrap( ~ type, scales = 'free_y') +
    theme(axis.line.x = element_line(),
          axis.ticks.x = element_line(),
          strip.placement = "outside")  
}

purrr::map2(c("A", "B"), c("bottom", "top"), make_plot) %>% 
  wrap_plots()
```

[image]